# Google Cloud Platform Get Request from Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I'm looking to make a HTTP get request from Google Tag Manager as a custom Javascipt to a GCP function and have it return a value. I understand the response could be slow but that's okay.

I have been able to create the function within GCP and when I call it from a browser with just the HTTP URL I get the expected response. Great but....when I call if with a HTTP Request variable I get tripped up on the CORS access. I've gone in a made the function publicly accessible but that doesn't solve my issue. Have added the cors = require but still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function reqListener () {
console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://us-central1-something.cloudfunctions.net/a_test?column=visitNumber&name=bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801&visit=1501651467");
oReq.send();
```

Comment: Does [this page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CORS headers on the function response, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  help you to allow all domains `*` or restrict the origins (domains), that are allowed to get information.

This is an example of a function that can be executed only in the domain `https://example.com`

```
exports.corsEnabledFunctionAuth = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers
  
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://example.com');

  // if you want allow any domain plese use this line and comment the previous line
  // res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // please put your current code
    res.send('Hello World!');
};
```